# Shape of contour of Laplacian

Tags: partial-derivative

On a revision book for maths I found a question asking for the shape of the contour where "Laplacian" (sum of 2nd partial derivatives in perpendicular directions) is zero?

$$ f(x,y) = e^{-(x^2+y^2)} $$

So assuming that "Laplacian" is 2nd partial derivative, I try to do the following:

$$f_{xx} =-2e^{-(x^2+y^2)}(1-2x^2)$$
$$f_{yy} =-2e^{-(x^2+y^2)}(1-2y^2)$$

And I try to sum them ending with:

$$f_{xx} + f_{yy} = -2e^{-(x^2+y^2)}((1-2x^2)+(1-2y^2))$$
$$f_{xx} + f_{yy} = -4e^{-(x^2+y^2)}(1-x^2-y^2)$$

So what's the contour for this when it is equal to zero, is what I think the question asks
$$f_{xx} + f_{yy} = 0$$
$$-4e^{-(x^2+y^2)}(1-x^2-y^2) = 0$$

How can I find the shape of the contour from this stage?

Answer (score 3):

We would like to find the contour describing the points on which
$$
-4e^{-(x^2+y^2)}(1-x^2-y^2) = 0
$$
Now, this expression can only be zero if we have
$$
-4e^{-(x^2+y^2)} = 0
$$
which never happens (why?) or if we have
$$
1-x^2-y^2 = 0 \implies x^2 + y^2 = 1
$$
Now, what contour is described by the equation $x^2 + y^2 = 1$?

Comment: should be into a circle?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I finally got what the question aimed at, I was very close!

Comment: @graphtheory92 indeed you were!  Glad I could give you a nudge in the right direction.